# How to use yml file in my cucumber test?

Tags: cucumber, yaml

I want to use config.yml file in my cucumber-test. I whrite such like this:

**test_config.yml:**

```
group_name: animals
learn_group_name: dogs
card_box_name: cats
```

**cucumber_test.rb:**

```
require `watir-webdriver`
require `yaml`

def read_config
  config = YAML.load(File.read(`/home/profile/Desktop/cucumber/test_config.yml`))
  @group = config[`group_name`]
  @learn_group = config[`learn_group_name`]
  @card_box = config[`card_box_name`]
end

puts `Group = #{@group}`
puts `Learn group = #{@learn_group}`
puts `Card box = #{@card_box}`
...
```

**in console (terminal):**

```
Group = 
Learn group = 
Card box =
...
```

But what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Before do
  @host                         ||= YML["host"]
  @group_name_for_search        ||= YML["group_name_for_search"]
  @learn_group_name_for_search  ||= YML["learn_group_name_for_search"]
  @card_box_name_for_search     ||= YML['card_box_name_for_search']
end
```

I must to define, before the cucumber steps, Before do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad code example.

You are you using backticks (`) instead of quotes ("). That will cause problems. A lot of problems.

The problem is not related to cucumber or watir-webdriver gems. You are defining instance variables (`@group`...) in a method (`read_config`) but then you are never calling the method.

Please update the question with more realistic example.